Recent horror movie with a little girl and a demon
In the movie the dad is an architect and working on the house they live in. The demon ends up crawling out of the unrenovated part or the house and the door to it is in the little girl's room upstairs. The little girl gets the demon attached to her and she ends up killing her mom in bed next to her dad sleeping with a hammer. In the end the dad takes the girl away and he gets controlled by the demon and stabs himself in the neck. The movie ends with the lil girl laying down talking to the demon.
The dad was sleeping next to the mom when the lil girl killed her with a hammer. Pretty disturbing scene. The demon makes him stab himself in the neck. He is like in a trance. Earlier in the movie the demon makes him walk into the door in the girl's room and perform some seance on him. And yes the demon wanted to take the girl with him, he acted almost like a father to her. She wasn't scared of him at all.
It's filmed kinda like a paranormal activity with the diff cameras and all but it isn't a paranormal activity. It's driving my wife and I nuts. Was a newer movie, like post 2010.

(FYI: the angels-and-demons tag is for the movie called Angels and Demons)

Oops my bad :-)

The dad sleeps with a hammer? Does the dad kill himself thinking he's killing the demon or the demon just kills him? Ends with little girl talking to the demon, like they're friends now? I'm really not trying to nitpick, but these are vague points.

No the dad was sleeping next to the mom when the lil girl killed her with a hammer. Pretty disturbing scene. The demon makes him stab himself in the neck. He is like in a trance. Earlier in the movie the demon makes him walking into the door in the girls room and performs some seance on him. And yes the demon wanted to take the girl with him he acted almost like a father to her. She wasn't scared of him at all.

It's filmed kinda like a paranormal activity with the diff cameras and all but it isn't a paranormal activity.

Sounds like the found footage horror film Infernal from 2015.

A happy young couple welcomes their first child shortly after getting married. Their joy quickly turns to fear when the girl starts acting strangely and unexplained phenomena start happening around the house. Fearing their daughter could be possessed, the parents call in a priest to perform an exorcism, but when that goes horribly wrong, the parents start to wonder if they can break their child free from the evil spirit that has taken over her body and soul and if she can be saved before it's too late.

She bludgeons her mom with a hammer and I'm pretty sure the dad gets possessed at some point and stabs himself in the throat. Here's the trailer:




Is it any good? 3.3/10 stars on imdb ::shudder::

That's it!!! Ty. Yes it was amazing.
